# Which of the following subsets of $P_2$ (polynomials of degree 2 or less) are subspaces of $P_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to decide whether or not a list of subsets of $P_2$ (polynomials of degree 2 or less) are also subspaces of $P_2$:

A. $\{p(t) \mid p'(t)+1p(t)+9=0\}$

B. $\{p(t) \mid p(0)=7\}$

C. $\{p(t) \mid \int_0^1 p(t) \,\mathrm{dt}=0\}$

D. $\{p(t) \mid p'(5)=p(6)\}$.

---

I already know the rules:

1) check if zero vector belongs to the subset

2) check if, for scalars $a$, $b$ and vectors $v$, $w$, if $av+bw$ is a vector of the subset.

---

I am very confused as to how to apply the rules. I feel (according to some rough trial and error) like A, B, and D are not subspaces, while C is.

Comment: You've got the right answers, so you can't be all that confused.  Can you show us more concretely where your confusion lies?

Comment: Basically, I just find a polynomial that fits the description given. Then I check if the zero vector gives a right answer (p(t)=0, then let p(t) be x; (0)=0 is true). Then I check if p(t1)+p(t2)=p(t1+t2). The issue is, I feel like checking a single polynomial isnt enough. What if I got lucky and choose a polynomial that happens to follow the rules?

Comment: @saulspatz Are you sure my answer is correct?https://imgur.com/IH7XmK1 The system says it's wrong. There are 6 subsets, but two of them are in common with my friend's version and he got a full marks on that question (meaning the issue is with the above 4).

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too quickly.  D is correct also.  If you follow the example in my answer you can quickly check them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A,B) Not a subspace since $p(t)=0\notin S$

---

C) Surely, $p(t)=0\in S$. Also if $p_1(t),p_2(t)\in S$ then we can write $$\int_0^1p_1(t)dt=0\\\int_0^1p_2(t)dt=0\\\Longrightarrow\\\int_0^1ap_1(t)+bp_2(t)dt=0\\a,b\in \Bbb R\\\Longrightarrow ap_1(t)+bp_2(t)\in S$$therefore $S$ is a subspace.

---

D) Similarly $p(t)=0\in S$ since $p'(5)=p(6)=0$. Furthermore from $p_1(t),p_2(t)\in S$ $$p'_1(5)=p_1(6)\\p'_2(5)=p_2(6)$$and we can write $$ap_1'(5)+bp_2'(5)=ap_1(6)+bp_2(6)$$therefore $$(ap_1+bp_2)'(5)=(ap_1+bp_2)(6)$$and hence $$(ap_1+bp_2)(t)\in S$$which means that $S$ is a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Finding one polynomial that doesn't follow the rules is enough to prove it isn't a subspace, but when you want to show it *is* a subspace you need a logical argument.  To show that C is a subspace you need to show first, that $)\in P$ (obvious) and second that $p,q\in P\implies ap+bq\in P$ for scalars $a,b.$  That meanes we are given $$\int_0^1 p(t)\mathrm{dt} = \int_0^1 q(t)\mathrm{dt} = 0$$ and we have to show that $$\int_0^1 ap(t)+bq(t)\mathrm{dt}=0$$ for any real numbers $a, b.$  But of course, this is true by the basic rules of integration, and we're done.

Comment: So the others are not subspaces?

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa No, D is a subspace also.  You can use this same method to check it yourself.